# CSS page-break-inside:avoid; not functional

Tags: css, page-break

I have been advised that said CSS `page-break-inside:avoid;` would prevent elements being printed between 2 pages.

On this directions print out this simply does not work on all tested browsers so far. The CSS .instruction has this applied yet prints across pages.

Example: http://www.golfbrowser.com/A4/directions.php?start=PARIS&end=SL42ES

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just add a print stylesheet or use a media query and a breaking div or just add the style to the elements in your html that need braking when printing.

Try adding this after every long block of content that you think needs breaking:

```
<div class="break">&nbsp;</div>
```

And as for your css just add this:

```
.break {
  display:none;
} //place inside your regular stylesheet file

@media print {
   .break {
       display:block; 
       page-break-after:always
    }
}
```

This method works in most modern browsers, including IE8+.

Comment: This is a horrible work around. If you are trying to fit multiple div in multiple pages, you are restricting 1 div per page instead of actually page break when this block doesn't fit. This work around doesn't even come close to what page-break-inside intended to do.

Comment: @Churk i dont think you understood the question and my answer. The point was to prevent multiple divs from printing on the same page, and not trying to fit them in.

Comment: @andrews Ilich This is what it said `would prevent elements being printed between 2 pages` nothing about printing each element on their own page. And this is what the whole point of `page-break-inside:avoid;` suppose to do.

Comment: @Churk my method above should work the same way, you're only inserting a page break "after" the element as opposed to preventing it all together.

Comment: your solution will cause a page break in every element that has page break after. I think the question is, is there a way to say if more than 1 block element can fit into a page, then do so until the element that would span more than 1 page, the page break before for that one which span more than 1 page. And that is what page-break-inside:avoid suppose to do if it is implemented.

Comment: in the world of printing, where page-break-before/after/inside are actually being use for, before/after:always is never a good solution cuz if you have a block element that is a 1 liner, you just printed out a large blank page with 1 line on it.

Answer (score 0):

The page-break-inside property is only supported by Opera.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pagebi.asp

Comment: w3school does not provide correct information about 50% of the time. and this is one of it. IE7 and IE8 and IE9 supports it, as long as the doctype is set to strict mode instead of quirks mode.

Comment: Really?  Aside from your personal experience, are there any articles that share this viewpoint?   BTW, your post is about 9 months late which some would categorize as a necro-post.

Comment: Its necro only if I am trying to revive it. I am trying to find a solution to page-break-inside:avoid; that works cross browser. So yes I am visiting all post even 9 months old post if I can find something that can help.

Comment: I think this link is now out of date; try: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/page-break-inside